# I need to Use one Slider to move Multi sliders using html and js

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding at all I am using Esp8266 to make an aquarium control as a hobby
I need to make this input range to control all LED, the code that I used is changing the value but I need to change the cursor position too, its moving but randomly after a lot of moving to the Main Slider than

```
<p class="switch">
                    <input type="range" onmousemove="updateSliderPWMAll(this)" id="slider1" min="0" max="255" step="1"
                        value="0" class="slider">
                </p>
                <p class="state">Brightness: <span id="sliderValue1"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <p class="card-title"> White LED</p>
                <p class="switch">
                    <input type="range" onmousemove="updateSliderPWM(this)" id="slider2" min="0" max="255" step="1"
                        value="0" class="slider">
                </p>
                <p class="state">Brightness: <span id="sliderValue2"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <p class="card-title"> Worm LED</p>
                <p class="switch">
                    <input type="range" onmousemove="updateSliderPWM(this)" id="slider3" min="0" max="255" step="1"
                        value="0" class="slider">
                </p>
                <p class="state">Brightness: <span id="sliderValue3"></span> </p>
            </div>


and this is the JS Code :

function updateSliderPWM(element) {
    var sliderNumber = element.id.charAt(element.id.length - 1);
    var sliderValue = document.getElementById(element.id).value;
    document.getElementById("sliderValue" + sliderNumber).innerHTML = sliderValue;
    console.log(sliderValue);
    websocket.send(sliderNumber + "s" + sliderValue.toString());
}

function updateSliderPWMAll(element) {
    var sliderNumber = element.id.charAt(element.id.length - 1);
    var sliderValue = document.getElementById(element.id).value;
    document.getElementById("sliderValue" + sliderNumber).innerHTML = sliderValue;

    var states = document.querySelectorAll(".state span");
    var switchs = document.querySelectorAll(".switch input");

    for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        states[i].innerHTML = sliderValue;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < switchs.length; i++) {
        switchs[i].setAttribute("value", sliderValue);
        websocket.send(switchs[i].className.replace("slider", "") + "s" + sliderValue.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the `oninput` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do. But you need to notice that your code need to be modified. Your HTML is not clean and could be improved

**HTML**

```
<p class="switch">
    <input type="range" onmousemove="updateSliderPWMAll(this)" id="slider1" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" class="slider">
</p>
<p class="state">Brightness: <span id="sliderValue1"></span></p>
<p class="switch">
    <input type="range" onmousemove="updateSliderPWMAll(this)" id="slider2" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" class="slider">
</p>
<p class="state">Brightness: <span id="sliderValue2"></span></p>

<p class="switch">
    <input type="range" onmousemove="updateSliderPWMAll(this)" id="slider3" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="0" class="slider">
</p>
<p class="state">Brightness: <span id="sliderValue3"></span> </p>
```

**Javascript**

```
function updateSliderPWMAll(element) {
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
var states = document.querySelectorAll('.state span');

sliders.forEach(slider => {
    slider.value = element.value;
});

states.forEach(state => {
    state.innerHTML = element.value;
});
}
```